# How to find a html element in drupal files?

Tags: php, drupal

As simple as this probably is, I cant find an html element in Drupal 7 files. It's is my first time using drupal 7. Its not my project and im trying to locate for example form:

```
<form class="commerce-add-to-cart commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-eas1da13sdasqew13tkasda52s">
```

when i type in CTRF+F search words "commerce-add-to-cart" i cant find anything...
How can i locate things in project files easier?

Comment: You can not just go and assume, that everything you find in the HTML output, must also be found exactly like that somewhere in the PHP source code. This form is likely dynamically generated. The class name could be assembled out of multiple parts, it could come from the configuration/settings, etc.

Comment: Don't now D7, however there's big chance that's some kind of plugin/extension which generates forms. That's very popular in CMS'

Comment: I know that forms are created in certain way in drupal. But how can i just go to a page as an admin and just find a module or template for one component?

Comment: Where do you press `CTRL+F`? and what scope do you search? Using good IDE you should find something. It may be in some HTML, PHP files or even third party templates with custom file extensions.

Comment: Download full source of the page and search for string in all possible files (you can exclude graphics of course)

Comment: Im using NetBeans :( CTRL+F im using in a file where are stored all modules and templates

Comment: HTML Forms are generated from `drupal_render()` from `drupal_get_form()`. The form definition is probably a function named "commerce_add_to_cart_form", in the "commerce?" module, or something like this. To alter it, you should use a [MODULE_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/7.x-1.x/modules/cart/commerce_cart.module#L1897

Rather than using CTRF+F to search for strings in the codebase, try using `grep` in the command line instead.

Also, Drupal tends to generate classes and IDs so a string search isn't always reliable. I'd recommend scanning through the module that generates the block/entity (i.e. "add to cart form" = "commerce_cart module")